# Why can you access the os module from path.__dict__ in python?

Tags: python

The code:

```
from os import path
path.__dict__['os'].system("/bin/sh")
```

Allows me to make a shell in python. I am curious why the os module can be accessed through the path class, when I didn't explicitly import the entire os module. I have read a few articles on **dict**, and how it stores the variables, methods, to the class etc. But I didn't find that it would keep the module it came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have anything special to do with `__dict__`; you can also get it as just `path.os`.  The `os.path` module imports the `os` module.  That means that the name `os` is accessible from `os.path`.  Anytime a module does `import foo`, you can access `foo` via that module just like you'd access anything else in the module.  Modules are just normal objects, and imported modules are accessible just like classes or functions or anything else in a module.